# Background data ski areas

Tags: geospatial, ski

For an assignment, I'm trying to visualize a specific ski route. The sample is taken with a GPS tracker in Obergurgl & Hoghgurgl, Austria. I am using QGIS for this assignment. I could insert the trace using vector lines in QGIS. But now I want to add some background data, like streets, heights, buildings for instance. Does anyone know how to do so or where to find the appropriate data?

Comment: I now found fatmap, can this be used?

Comment: this seems to be GIS question, since it's tool specific. Or?

Comment: i could see it either way, although considering this is qgis based....i'd lean to gis se. but i bet you they point them right back here to get the data.

Comment: can you link to fatmap? if it has gis data, it can most likely be added to your qgis map.